# Python2.7 package installed in right path but not found

Tags: python, module, pip

I used pip to install all python packages, and the path is:
 PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages"

I found all the packages I tried to install were installed under this path, but when I tried to import them, it always said module not found.

MacBook-Air:~ User$ pip install tweepy
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): tweepy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

import tweepy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in

ImportError: No module named tweepy

I tried with tweepy, httplib2, oauth and some others, none of these can work.

Can anyone tell how can I solve this problem?

Thanks!!!!

Comment: what does `which python` output?

Comment: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python

Comment: Based on your comment, it appears that pip is installing your libraries to an installation of python that's not the same as the one you are executing the import command in.

Comment: and `which -a python`? a;so try running a shell with `/usr/local/bin/python` and importing the modules

Comment: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python

Comment: I feel like it should be this problem but I don't know how to resolve this. Do I need to uninstall python first?

Answer (score 0):

Feel like comment has too many things..

So as @Zahir Jacobs said, this problem is because pip is installing all packages in different path. After I moved all the packages to $which python path, I can import these modules now.

But the following question is, if I still want to use pip installation in the future, I have to move it by manually again. is there anyway to change the path for pip? 
I tried to move pip package, but it returned:

MacBook-Air:~ User$ pip install tweepy

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in 
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

ImportError: No module named pkg_resources